# Converting PDFs into thumbnails with iMagick PHP

Tags: php

I'm attempting to convert the icons for our PDFs into thumbnails of the PDF using iMagick for our clients, but when I use this code:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url($pdf->value); ?>" target="_blank" class="view-my-pdf" >
<?php if($pdf->splash_url == ""){
    // echo '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>'
    $pdf = $im;
    $im = new imagick('file.pdf[0]');
    $im->setImageFormat('jpg');
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    echo $im;
} else { ?>
    <!-- <img class="pdf_thumb" src="//placehold.it/500x500&text=Worksheet"> -->
    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
<?php } ?>
```

It doesn't defaults to the icon view as directed in the else portion of my if statement.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is that all from one file? You can't `echo` and then `header`. What is `$pdf->splash_url`'s value? If it's `null`, `false` or `''`, then `$pdf->splash_url == ""` will be true, running the `then` part of the `if`.